# Tag [volatility] should be a synonym for tag [volatile]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I was just asked to review a suggested tag wiki for the [volatility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volatility) tag, which has 88 questions.  There's also a tag [volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volatile) with 1163 questions.

It seems to me that these should be synonyms, and [volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volatile) is the better tag name.

Comment: There is also a third meaning: it's the name of a memory forensics framework (http://www.volatilityfoundation.org). Many of the tagged questions are about it.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: That's interesting. Also wholly different from the tag wiki information that was proposed.  If that is a sensible use for the tag, I've no problem as long as the tag wiki makes that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232313/how-to-calculate-the-monthly-volatility-in-excel-vba-under-column-time-series), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828622/calculating-the-stock-price-volatility-from-a-3-columns-csv) and some others interpret the *volatility* tag as denoting the financial property of shares and fonds, and we have even this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40817764/1435475) assuming a third interpretation.

Since application domain terms like this are of limited use for programming and looked up the tag description, which turned out to be empty.

My attempt to clarify this by proposing a tag explanation was rejected, however, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15876395) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15876394). The only useful comment was, that it should be a a synonym of the *volatile* tag, which resulted in the question above.

I'm still somewhat annoyed, that the attempt to clarify was rejected, since imho even an insufficient explanation is better than none to avoid future misuse based on different assumption of the meaning. It is also worth to note, that most questions concerning financial volatility have got a comment, that they should be asked elsewhere.

Comment: That second explanation was "look at Wikipedia". Did you really think that would be approved?!?

Comment: I can't recognize this as a valid argument to reject the first; and even that would serve as disambiguation, to clarify what the tag is supposed to represent.

Comment: For that one, the review rejections have the reason for the rejection: *Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. See the help center for more guidance.*

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Comparing the first sentence of my answer with your last comment leaves me as puzzled as the reason given for the rejection; exactly the ambiguousness is what I tried to resolve. If the tag description was empty since the invention of the tag, the need for describing can't be that pressing and is surely less important than a tag, which is undefined and applied arbitrarily.

Comment: Reading the rejection message, it seems obvious to me. The excerpt "should describe why and when the tag should be used". Your attempt explained what the tag word means. If you had written something like "The volatility tag should be used when asking a question regarding the reasons for and appropriate use of the `volatile` keyword in C, Java, and other programming languages", you might have had a better outcome.

Comment: I mostly agree with Mike, except that the term cross-referenced was `volatile`, not `volatility`.  The suggested wiki information might be semi-appropriate for the `volatile` tag (aka [tag:volatile]), but it was not appropriate for `volatility`.  Even for `volatile`, the suggested information was very weak — I would probably not have accepted it for that either.